# Split a file using delimeter "/" in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a file like

```
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/foo/something_else.csv, 2013-11-25, username, group
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/split/public/something_else.csv, 2013-11-27, username, group
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/dashboard/private/tags/test.csv, 2013-11-25, user, no_group
```

I need the output in below format

Output:

```
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/foo, 2013-11-25, username, group
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/split, 2013-11-27, username, group
/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/dashboard, 2013-11-25, user, no_group
```

Could anyone please provide me the solution for this scenario...
Thanks

Comment: what did you get when you used from sys import argv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `argv` module. `argv` is an attribute of the `sys` module:

```
import sys
script, first, second, third = sys.argv
```

or use:

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
```

This assumes that you are passing exactly 3 command-line arguments to your script.

Comment: Also note that the script won't run if it does not have exactly 3 argument.

Comment: @Nico Of course, but that comment probably belongs on the original question itself, not on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `argv` is NOT a python package. The statement `import sys` is for importing the `sys` package, `argv` is a variable of this package which holds the arguments of your program.
After importing sys: `import sys` you can use argv like this:

```
script, first, second, third = sys.argv
print "the script is called:", script
print "First script:", first
print "Second script:", second
print "third script:", third
```

or alternative you could use `from sys import argv` like hcwhsa pointed out and use it the same way you post.